# how to refer a column with integer data type foreign key in existing table with columns values

Tags: postgresql

In my parent table (empid integer) is primary key. In my child table have some columns with values. I need to add a column (empid integer not null) in my child table ,i can't add a column.Because the child table have values. I need a add column with default value. If i add column with default 0.I need to have the 0 value in my parent table. So any other way to refer the parent table and set the default value.    I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: You can add a nullable column, fill it with the correct data, and make it not nullable.

Comment: Please don't tag other RDBMS's other than the one you are using. I've removed these for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the column first with a default value before declaring the foreign key constraint. Prefill it correctly, then create the foreign key constraint. 
A bad way is to create a row with 0 empid in the parent table, then create the column in the child table with default value 0 while having the foreign key constraint, but you shouldn't need this, it's absurd.

Comment: There is any other way to add a column with data type integer default.
Default value not 0. Any other choice

Comment: No, I am newly add a column. I can't set the default value for new column

Comment: Okay, you can add an empty column, with no default value. Try adding that. 
After that, you can fill with the correct data you want.

Comment: Yeah, It's right. But i wants to add the not null column.